# Matlab: how to write a vector of a few points as a continuous function?

Tags: matlab, function, vector

I have two vectors:

```
x = [0; 1; 2]
y = [2.0000; 0; -14.7781]
```

If I will plot x and y I will see three points on the `xy`-plane. But I want to connect those three points and get them as a continuous function:

```
y = f(x),
y(0) = 2;
y(1) = 0;
y(2) = -14.7781;
y(0.5) = value between 2 and 0.
```

For example `y` can be treated as a ZOH (zero order held) continuous signal.

I saw that MATLAB has a function called `d2c`, which converts a model from discrete to continuous time. But have no idea how to link it with the vector I have already. How to do 
this with MATLAB?

Comment: would you mind to restate your question in a more comprehensible way? Provide us with an example of what you aim to achieve and a piece of code showing your effort so far.

Comment: You seem to have a complete lack of understanding of the mathematical concept of a 'function'. ***Three points do no determine a curve*** (especially when there are not even 'points', but just some 1-D `x`-data). In fact, three points determine an *infinite* amount of continuous functions. We are more than willing to help you, but please, restate your question so that 1) it actually makes sense, and 2) is clear to us what you want to accomplish.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis: +1 for you!

Comment: Actually `plot(x,y)` does not just give three points but will give you the linear interpolation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, your latest edit improves the situation a lot.

However, you still do not demarcate the problem sufficiently.

ZOH would be as simple as

```
    >> x = [0; 1; 2];
    >> y = [2.0000; 0; -14.7781];
    >> f = @(new_x) y(find(x <= new_x, 1, 'last'));
    >> f(0.5)

    ans =
        2
```

However, this is not what I think you mean, as the `y(0.5) = value between 2 and 0` part of your question indicates.

Perhaps you want a linearly interpolated value:

```
>> f = @(new_x) interp1(x,y, new_x);
>> f(0.5)

ans = 
    1
```

Or a cubic splines interpolation:

```
>> f = @(new_x) interp1(x,y, new_x, 'spline');
>> f(0.5)

ans =    
    2.5973
```

What I'm asking is: what model best describes your signal when the sample time would decrease to infinitesmal values?

Comment: Thank you, it is what I needed. I add f function to [y]=dsolve('Dy=(y*2)-f', inits); Then do this: yy=eval(vectorize(y)); and get an error: "??? Error using ==> eval
Undefined function or method 'rdivide' for input arguments of type 'function_handle'."
Maybe do you know why?

Answer (score 1):

An nth degree polynomial can have at most n-1 turning points. Thus, we can do a polynomial regression:

```
% Input data
yy = [2.0000; 0; -14.7781];

% Parameters
n = length(yy)-1;
x = (0:1:n).';

% Regression
p = polyfit(x,yy,n);

% Plot
f = polyval(p,x);
figure
plot(x,yy,'o',x,f,'-')
```